# Manga or manhwa about someone who woke up in a fantasy world, simultaneously stuck in a girl and a guy's bodies

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I need help finding a manhwa/manga about someone who woke up in a fantasy world simultaneously stuck in a girl and a guy's bodies.

I read it when I was just starting to read manga and manhwa, so I didn't really have the thought of bookmarking it. But from what I remember there was a training arc with the guy training with a beast, and the girl trains at an academy, and eventually both bodies fight each other in a tournament. The girl and guy share the same mind and personality. If anyone knows anything about this, then it would help me very much.

Comment: Do you remember when approximately you read it (which year)?

Comment: @Hueman502 - Welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, please [upvote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that answer and mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) so we know to keep looking. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Might this be *[After Transformation, Mine and Her Wild Fantasy](http://After%20Transformation,%20Mine%20and%20Her%20Wild%20Fantasy)*...?

[image]

> When other people experience a body transformation, it is inevitably either male to female or female to male.
>
> Me? I wake up to find myself transformed into two different bodies.
>
> Both a male body and a female body, one conscience operating two bodies, all sorts of embarrassing moments.
>
> Walking together normally makes other people think that I am sweethearts with my other-self, such sadness.
>
> Also, the entire business of a hero rescuing the beautiful maiden, I call Bull.
>
> I get slashed by a sword and my female body gets abducted, and he wants me to thank him?!?! Can it be less of a tragedy?

This is a manhua, and the story begins with someone waking up inside two bodies; one male, named Tyre, and the other female, named Lunaria. There's an academy in the story, named Avalon Academy, and Lunaria studies magic, while Tyre is trained in swordsmanship by a large crab named Kamin, which could be the beast you mentioned. Both Lunaria and Tyre also take part in a few tournament-style competitions, although I didn't see a match where they fought each other. I wonder if you might be misremembering that part.

[image]

[image]